# How can I use migrations in production, but not in test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions, ef-core-3.0

I have a sql db in production, (and dev), but I'd like to use in memory for my tests. In my class constructor I was calling `dbcontext.database.migrate()`, but the in memory db doesn't like that. If I take it out of the constructor, my test works, but I don't know where to put it for the production code to use it.

`Constructor:`

```
public ParseAndRefreshDealerData(DbContextExtensions dbContext, IAzureStorage azureStorage)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _azureStorage = azureStorage;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need some sort of flag to inhibit the migration call for your tests.  If you're using Visual Studio, you should be able to do this with the `#ifndef DEBUG` directive, using the DEBUG build configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can eventually use [IsInMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydatabasefacadeextensions.isinmemory?view=efcore-3.1) extension method as criteria for skipping `Migrate` call, e.g.

```
if (!dbContext.Database.IsInMemory())
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Thought I had tried that, but didn't find it. Must not have included the dependencies in the project.